# About origins of Dors Venabili

Tags: isaac-asimov, foundation

This question itself contains spoilers which may, well spoil, your reading experience of books *Prelude to Foundation* and *Forward the Foundation*. Proceed with caution!

> In the mentioned books, it was revealed that Dors Venabili is actually a robot and that she is working for R. Daneel Olivaw (who also goes by name Chetter Hummin and Eto Demerzel). It was clear that she takes orders from him and somewhat reveres him. It was implied that she was much younger than him, i.e. constructed not long before events in the books. Was it anywhere established how old she really was and if it was Daneel himself who constructed her?

Comment: I don't believe Dors' origins were ever addressed in the core canon. I do know that in the post Asimov books Dors has more screen time, but as I haven't read those I can't comment further.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you read the SECOND FOUNDATION SERIES (not about the Second Foundation, but the second series about Foundation stuff) Dors plays a HUGE role.

In the timeline at the end of the last book, [Foundation's Triumph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foundation%27s_Triumph) by David Brin (approved by the Asimov family), it is stated that

> Dors is constructed 13 years before Hari Seldon is born. Her primary role is to play his nursemaid, teacher and then protector. SHe and Hari fall in love and she becomes his wife.

Also at the end of Foundation's Triumph

> Dors  is headed to see Hari one last time before his death. The book is left open ended, allowing for her and Lodovic Trema, another Humaniform robot, to form a loose partnership for more adventures.

Give the second trilogy a read: you won't be disappointed!